# Problema con el valor de una cookies si le paso una variable

Tags: javascript, captcha

estoy intentando pasar el valor de una variable como valor de una cookie, pero solo consiguo que el valor sea el nombre de la variable.

```
       /* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

var code = '';
let btn = document.getElementById('btnEnvio'); // boton envio
function captcha() {
    var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    }
    code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g;
    crearCookie('cogido', code, 120);
    creaIMG(code);
}

function validCaptcha(txtInput) {
    var string1 = removeSpaces(leerCookie('codigo'));
    var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById(txtInput).value);
   
    if (string1 === string2) {
        document.getElementById("btnEnvio").disabled = false;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        captcha();
        return false;
    }
}
function removeSpaces(string) {
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}

function creaIMG(texto) {
    var ctxCanvas = document.getElementById('captcha').getContext('2d');
    var fontSize = "30px";
    var fontFamily = "Arial";
    var width = 250;
    var height = 50;
    //tamaño
    ctxCanvas.canvas.width = width;
    ctxCanvas.canvas.height = height;
    //color de fondo
    ctxCanvas.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctxCanvas.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //puntos de distorsión
    ctxCanvas.setLineDash([7, 10]);
    ctxCanvas.lineDashOffset = 5;
    ctxCanvas.beginPath();
    var line;
    for (var i = 0; i < (width); i++) {
        line = i * 5;
        ctxCanvas.moveTo(line, 0);
        ctxCanvas.lineTo(0, line);
    }
    ctxCanvas.stroke();
    //formato texto
    ctxCanvas.direction = 'ltr';
    ctxCanvas.font = fontSize + " " + fontFamily;
    //texto posicion
    var x = (width / 9);
    var y = (height / 3) * 2;
    //color del borde del texto
    ctxCanvas.strokeStyle = "yellow";
    ctxCanvas.strokeText(texto, x, y);
    //color del texto
    ctxCanvas.fillStyle = "red";
    ctxCanvas.fillText(texto, x, y);
}


// Funcion para crear una cookies
function crearCookie(nombre, valor, exsegun) {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(valor);
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exsegun));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = nombre + "=" + valor + ";" + expires;
  }

// Funcion para leer una cookies
function leerCookie(nombre) {
    var name = nombre + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Necesito el valor de la variable code, que es un captcha que se genera, como os digo solo consigo que el valor sea code, por lo tanto siempre me tira false la comparación y no entro. Gracias

Comment: Actualizado el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve debugueando tu código y si genera la cookie, el problema que yo veo le das muy poco tiempo de vida, 150 milisegundos, genera la cookie y la elimina casi al instante, ahorita para fines prácticos la deje a 60000 milisegundos que debería ser 1 minuto.

`crearCookie('codigo', code, 60000);`

El otro problema que encontré e que cuando generas tu cookie se genera con el nombré `cogido`, y cuando la mandas llamar es con el nombre `codigo`.

```
crearCookie('codigo', code, 60000);
leerCookie('codigo');
```

Este es todo el mismo código, únicamente con los cambios que aplique.

```
function captcha() {
    var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    }
    code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g;
    crearCookie('codigo', code, 60000);
    creaIMG(code);
}

function validCaptcha(txtInput) {
    var string1 = removeSpaces(leerCookie('codigo'));
    var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById(txtInput).value);
    if (string1 === string2) {
        document.getElementById("btnEnvio").disabled = false;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        captcha();
        return false;
    }
}
function removeSpaces(string) {
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}

function creaIMG(texto) {
    var ctxCanvas = document.getElementById('captcha').getContext('2d');
    var fontSize = "30px";
    var fontFamily = "Arial";
    var width = 250;
    var height = 50;
    //tamaño
    ctxCanvas.canvas.width = width;
    ctxCanvas.canvas.height = height;
    //color de fondo
    ctxCanvas.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctxCanvas.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //puntos de distorsión
    ctxCanvas.setLineDash([7, 10]);
    ctxCanvas.lineDashOffset = 5;
    ctxCanvas.beginPath();
    var line;
    for (var i = 0; i < (width); i++) {
        line = i * 5;
        ctxCanvas.moveTo(line, 0);
        ctxCanvas.lineTo(0, line);
    }
    ctxCanvas.stroke();
    //formato texto
    ctxCanvas.direction = 'ltr';
    ctxCanvas.font = fontSize + " " + fontFamily;
    //texto posicion
    var x = (width / 9);
    var y = (height / 3) * 2;
    //color del borde del texto
    ctxCanvas.strokeStyle = "yellow";
    ctxCanvas.strokeText(texto, x, y);
    //color del texto
    ctxCanvas.fillStyle = "red";
    ctxCanvas.fillText(texto, x, y);
}


// Funcion para crear una cookies
function crearCookie(nombre, valor, exsegun) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exsegun));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = nombre + "=" + valor + ";" + expires;
}

// Funcion para leer una cookies
function leerCookie(nombre) {
    var name = nombre + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```